# Spring Expression Language nested projections

Tags: spring-el

Is there any way (or a workaround) to perform nested projection in expressions with access to parent projection context? What I want to evaulate is

```
collection.![#this.someList.?[#this.id == #parent.id]]
```

where `#parent` presumably refers to `#this` of `collection.!` projection.